# Toggle bit for a series of rows based on single row in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a table containing rows which are either 'headers' or 'normal', non-header entries. This is tracked by an `INTEGER` affinity column `IsHeader`.

Likewise, I have a column tracking if the row is 'Active'.

With a table 'Entries', and another column 'MCL_Row' used to find relevant rows, I can toggle the value of 'Active' using

```
UPDATE Entries SET(Active) = 
    (SELECT (~(Active&1))&(Active|1) WHERE MCL_Row = <target>) 
    WHERE MCL_Row = <target>;
```

This works, but if I want to toggle an entire group on or off based on the header, I can't use

```
UPDATE Entries SET(Active) = 
    (SELECT (~(Active&1))&(Active|1) WHERE S_Type = <typenum> AND IsHeader=1)
    WHERE S_Type = <typenum>;
```

because here, the SELECT subquery returns the one value I want, but multiple rows are updated. As a result, the first row gets the correct result, and subsequent rows satisfying the `WHERE S_Type = <typenum>` clause are updated with a `NULL` value.

How can I use the value returned by this subclause to set the values (identically) of multiple rows used by the `UPDATE` statement?

*Edit*: Perhaps the question was a little unclear originally, so adding some example before/after data.

Before:

```
MCL_Row  S_Type  Active  IsHeader
1        1       1       1
2        1       1       0
3        1       0       0
4        2       1       1
5        2       1       0
6        2       1       0
```

After setting S_Type=1 active via header:

```
MCL_Row  S_Type  Active  IsHeader
1        1       1       1
2        1       1       0
3        1      >1<      0
4        2       1       1
5        2       1       0
6        2       1       0
```

After setting S_Type=1 inactive via header:

```
MCL_Row  S_Type  Active  IsHeader
1        1      >0<      1
2        1      >0<      0
3        1       0       0
4        2       1       1
5        2       1       0
6        2       1       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st query

```
UPDATE  Entries 
SET     Active = 1-Active 
WHERE   MCL_Row = <target>
;
```

2nd query

```
UPDATE  Entries

SET     Active =   (select    1-h.Active 
                    from      Entries as h 
                    where     h.S_Type   = Entries.S_Type 
                          and h.IsHeader = 1
                    )

WHERE   S_Type = <typenum>
```

---

#### Demo

```
create table Entries (MCL_Row int,S_Type int,IsHeader int,active int);

insert into Entries (MCL_Row,S_Type,IsHeader,active) values
    (1,123,1,1)
   ,(2,123,0,0)
   ,(3,123,0,0)
   ,(4,123,0,1)
;
```

---

```
select * from Entries;
```

---

```
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| MCL_Row | S_Type | IsHeader | active |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1       | 123    | 1        | 1      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 2       | 123    | 0        | 0      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 3       | 123    | 0        | 0      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 4       | 123    | 0        | 1      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
```

---

```
UPDATE  Entries

SET     Active =   (select    1-h.Active 
                    from      Entries as h 
                    where     h.IsHeader = 1
                          and h.S_Type   = Entries.S_Type 
                    )
                    
WHERE   S_Type = 123 
;
```

---

```
select * from Entries;        
    
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| MCL_Row | S_Type | IsHeader | active |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1       | 123    | 1        | 0      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 2       | 123    | 0        | 1      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 3       | 123    | 0        | 1      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 4       | 123    | 0        | 1      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
```

---

```
UPDATE  Entries

SET     Active =   (select    1-h.Active 
                    from      Entries as h 
                    where     h.IsHeader = 1
                          and h.S_Type   = Entries.S_Type 
                    )
                    
WHERE   S_Type = 123 
;
```

---

```
select * from Entries;
```

---

```
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| MCL_Row | S_Type | IsHeader | active |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1       | 123    | 1        | 1      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 2       | 123    | 0        | 0      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 3       | 123    | 0        | 0      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 4       | 123    | 0        | 0      |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Seems like this changes the value of the header row, but not the other rows satisfying the `S_Type = 1` clause. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: This is a correlated sub-query. Logically, the inner query is executed based on value(s) from the outer query.

Comment: This changes of rows (header and non header) with the required S_Type to the toggled value of the header

Comment: Thank you for the demo - this confirms what I thought - so if I want them to have the same value (i.e. the same as the new 'Active' value for the row with 'IsHeader'=1, I should run the second query you listed and additionally update the 'IsHeader' row separately?

Comment: This doesn't work as I expected and I'm not easily surprised. Checking...

Comment: I've reported a SQLite bug

Comment: As a workaround - Avoid the correlation by replacing `Entries.S_Type`  with `<typenum>`

Comment: Thanks for all this - as you said, replacing Entries.S_Type with an explicit value makes this work as desired. Binding the same value twice isn't perfect, but it certainly isn't that bad and is completely workable. Perhaps in the future I can revert to the query you originally posted with the h.S_Type = Entries.S_Type.

Comment: This is claimed to be the standard SQLite behavior. I have asked to add it to the documentation.